# Cannot mount a splitted ISO after concatenation

Tags: installation, mount, iso

I have a splitted ISO (7 files of 7GB) which I concatenate with the terminal as

```
cat /Volumes/Blah/*.iso > /Volumes/Blah/concatenated.iso
```

I can see that the concatenated.iso file has size 7 x 7GB, but when I use any mounting software afterwards on Mac OSX, (tried Keka & Disk Utility), the mounted disk shows only a size of 7GB & seems to only contain the first one. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the split parts do not have headers of their own, and can simply be concatenated:

You need to ensure they are concatenated in the correct order. The order of `cat /Volumes/Blah/*.iso` is essentially undefined, it's likely not ordered alphabetically. Run `echo /Volumes/Blah/*.iso` to see what order you actually end up.

So list all the files manually in the correct order, like `cat /Volumes/Blah/foo_1.iso cat /Volumes/Blah/foo_2.iso cat /Volumes/Blah/foo_3.iso`. If you have a very large number of files you can employ a sub-shell with a `for` loop but if this is a one-time job you're probably faster just copy/paste/modify-ing the path of each file manually.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this tonight , I guess that will fix it!